# Uninstall Git completely on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-10.04, uninstall, git

I installed Git on Ubuntu Lucid (latest) manually as following.

```
cd ~/tmp

wget http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.7.0.6.tar.gz

tar -xzvf git-1.7.0.6.tar.gz
cd git-1.7.0.6.tar.gz
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Now, how can I completely uninstall it?

Comment: are the contents of `~/tmp/git-1.7xxxxx` still there?

Comment: You'll want to install packages through apt when possible. Ubuntu Lucid has the latest version of git in Apt as `git-core`.

Comment: @hasen, Yes the files are there in tmp.

Comment: @Zack, initially I couldn't find the git-core in package manager. Then I installed it via source. Later when I changed the source to US server, then I see the git-core package. But I've already installed it via source, hence the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this with the following step:

```
sudo find /usr/local -depth -iname 'git*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

That deleted all the git related files.
Then used the apt-get to install git-core.

The reason behind this trouble is:

- I installed git-1.7.xxx via source. But libcurl was not installed before, so that it couldn't clone the git/github repo via `http://` protocol http://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support

Comment: As long as you haven't installed 'gitarHero' on your system... ;-) (PS: I know the spelling isn't correct)

Comment: Don't forget about `.gitconfig` in `~`

Answer (score 6):

Use [installwatch](http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/installwatch.html) (aka checkinstall) to see what it actually installed, then delete the files. Note, this requires running `make install` again, just under installwatch.

Check, first to make sure an `uninstall` target does not exist (e.g try `make uninstall`). `make help` might also be of use.

Unless you *really* need a feature in a newer version of something that your distro packages (or unless they simply don't package it), its generally a good idea to install stuff using the package manager, for just this reason.

Comment: Installwatch runs on Windows - not sure it applies to Ubuntu.  Also, I think it would have to be installed before git to be useful.

Comment: Ah - that link is much better, and I hadn't seen it before so thanks ;o)

Comment: as @mike said, does this work after installing git?