# Linux: how to uninstall something that isn't a package...?

Tags: linux, uninstall, package-management, ruby

I installed ruby1.9.1 from source using `sudo make install`. How can I uninstall this?

Basically I just don't want 'ruby' to map to ruby1.9.1, but instead the default 1.8.7.

Also `sudo make uninstall` does nothing.

Comment: Did you run your `make uninstall` from the directory with the `./condigure`'d sources you used to install?

Comment: this might be a duplicate (in practical terms, regarding what answers can be posted) of http://superuser.com/questions/137592/uninstall-git-completely-on-ubuntu

Comment: i'm presuming your `sudo make unisntall` was a typo in the question post, not the command you actually tried?  cause that shouldn't work but `sudo make uninstall` *might*.

Comment: yes typo SU. Ruby has no uninstall.

Comment: installwatch doesn't help, because it wont reinstall unless i uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a ruby specific thing, so it almost now belongs in SO. Here is what to do (as per [this blog post](http://pivotallabs.com/users/chad/blog/articles/407-removing-old-ruby-source-installation-after-a-leopard-upgrade).

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ruby
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/irb
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/rake
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the makefile for a 'make uninstall' target. Sometimes they come with those.

Failing that, the best you can do is carefully read the 'make install' target and then manually undo what it did.